# Prevent reflow in absolutely positioned div

Tags: css

I've got an absolutely-positioned div that's animated with the `left` property. Unfortunately, it reflows when it hits the side of its parent. **How do I force the `#child` div to maintain its width, even when the right-hand side gets pushed out of the parent div?**

The child needs to maintain its original width, not just a fixed value. If there's less than 400px of text, I want `#child` to shrinkwrap to the text.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/baconscript/8fzd70v2/).

```
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}

#child{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; /* this animates between 0 and 90% */
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: Are you trying to make it not come back?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to maintain its width, even when `left`+`width` is greater than the width of the parent. I've just updated the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```css
#child {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

use

```css
#child {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```js
function to() {
  $('#child').animate({left:'90%'},{duration:2000, done: fro});
}

function fro() {
  $('#child').animate({left:0},{duration:2000, done: to});
}

to();
```

```css
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}

#child{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        Pour-over food truck proident occaecat YOLO, nihil Vice banh mi qui squid kogi. Asymmetrical flexitarian nihil, DIY Wes Anderson heirloom cillum artisan ethical hella drinking vinegar wolf Pinterest voluptate cupidatat. Odio exercitation pariatur freegan, letterpress McSweeney's quinoa qui typewriter seitan retro fanny pack. 90's nostrud, put a bird on it gluten-free irony Banksy cronut readymade High Life. Keytar mlkshk dolor et, quinoa Carles actually stumptown enim church-key qui cronut semiotics synth photo booth. Slow-carb accusamus XOXO, cornhole scenester fingerstache stumptown. Aliquip High Life sartorial Marfa actually.
    </div>
</div>
```

Or in this case, since `#parent` has `width: 500px`, the following will suffice

```css
#child {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```js
function to() {
  $('#child').animate({left:'90%'},{duration:2000, done: fro});
}

function fro() {
  $('#child').animate({left:0},{duration:2000, done: to});
}

to();
```

```css
#parent{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted black;
}

#child{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        Pour-over food truck proident occaecat YOLO, nihil Vice banh mi qui squid kogi. Asymmetrical flexitarian nihil, DIY Wes Anderson heirloom cillum artisan ethical hella drinking vinegar wolf Pinterest voluptate cupidatat. Odio exercitation pariatur freegan, letterpress McSweeney's quinoa qui typewriter seitan retro fanny pack. 90's nostrud, put a bird on it gluten-free irony Banksy cronut readymade High Life. Keytar mlkshk dolor et, quinoa Carles actually stumptown enim church-key qui cronut semiotics synth photo booth. Slow-carb accusamus XOXO, cornhole scenester fingerstache stumptown. Aliquip High Life sartorial Marfa actually.
    </div>
</div>
```